Unable to merge video and audio with GStreamer in C# - only video is recorded
I am working on a project using GStreamer in C# to record an RTSP stream. My goal is to combine both video and audio into a single MP4 file. Currently, the code only records the video, and I am unable to link the audio stream to the muxer. Below is the code I am using(its  POC so code is not perfect):
  private static async Task<Pipeline> InitializePipeline(int cameraId, string rtspUrl, string cameraName)
  {
      Gst.Application.Init();

      string pipelineName = $"rtsp-recording-pipeline-{cameraId}-{cameraName}";
      Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline(pipelineName);

      Element rtspSrc = ElementFactory.Make("rtspsrc", "source");
      Element videoDepay = null;
      Element videoParse = null;
      Element videoQueue = ElementFactory.Make("queue", "videoQueue");
      Element audioQueue = ElementFactory.Make("queue", "audioQueue");
      Element audioConvert = ElementFactory.Make("audioconvert", "audioConvert");
      Element audioEnc = ElementFactory.Make("avenc_aac", "audioEnc");
      Element muxer = ElementFactory.Make("splitmuxsink", "muxer");

      if (rtspSrc == null || videoQueue == null || audioQueue == null || audioConvert == null || audioEnc == null || muxer == null)
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"Failed to create elements for {pipelineName}.");
          return null;
      }

      string filePrefix = cameraName.Replace(" ", "_");
      string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
      string outputDirectory = Path.Combine("Recordings", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), filePrefix, "buffer");
      string outputDirectoryDest = Path.Combine("Recordings", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), filePrefix);
      Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);

      foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(outputDirectory))
      {
          try
          {
              File.Delete(file);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Console.WriteLine($"Error deleting file {file}: {ex.Message}");
          }
      }

      muxer.SetProperty("muxer-factory", new GLib.Value("mp4mux"));
      muxer.SetProperty("max-size-time", new GLib.Value((ulong)31000000000));
      muxer.SetProperty("location", new GLib.Value($"{outputDirectory}/{filePrefix}-{timestamp}-%05d.mp4"));

      muxer.Connect("format-location", (o, args) => FormatLocationCallback(o, args, outputDirectory, filePrefix, cameraId, outputDirectoryDest));

      pipeline.Add(rtspSrc, videoQueue, audioQueue, audioConvert, audioEnc, muxer);

      muxer.SyncStateWithParent();
      audioEnc.SyncStateWithParent();
      audioConvert.SyncStateWithParent();
      audioQueue.SyncStateWithParent();
      videoQueue.SyncStateWithParent();
      rtspSrc.SyncStateWithParent();

      rtspSrc.SetProperty("location", new GLib.Value(rtspUrl));
      rtspSrc.SetProperty("latency", new GLib.Value((uint)400));

      rtspSrc.PadAdded += (o, args) =>
      {
          var srcPad = args.NewPad;
          Console.WriteLine($"New pad added to rtspSrc: {srcPad.Name}");
          var caps = srcPad.QueryCaps().ToString();
          Console.WriteLine($"Caps of new pad: {caps}");

          if (caps.Contains("application/x-rtp"))
          {
              if (caps.Contains("encoding-name=(string)H264"))
              {
                  videoDepay = ElementFactory.Make("rtph264depay", "videoDepay");
                  videoParse = ElementFactory.Make("h264parse", "videoParse");
              }
              else if (caps.Contains("encoding-name=(string)H265"))
              {
                  videoDepay = ElementFactory.Make("rtph265depay", "videoDepay");
                  videoParse = ElementFactory.Make("h265parse", "videoParse");
              }

              if (videoDepay != null && videoParse != null)
              {
                  pipeline.Add(videoDepay, videoParse);
                  videoDepay.SyncStateWithParent();
                  videoParse.SyncStateWithParent();

                  if (srcPad.Link(videoDepay.GetStaticPad("sink")) != PadLinkReturn.Ok)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine($"Failed to link source pad to videoDepay sink pad.");
                      return;
                  }

                  videoDepay.Link(videoParse);
                  videoParse.Link(videoQueue);
                  videoQueue.Link(muxer);

                  Console.WriteLine("Video elements linked successfully.");
              }
          }
          else if (caps.Contains("audio/x-raw"))
          {
              var sinkPad = audioQueue.GetStaticPad("sink");
              if (sinkPad != null && srcPad.Link(sinkPad) == PadLinkReturn.Ok)
              {
                  audioQueue.SyncStateWithParent();
                  audioConvert.SyncStateWithParent();
                  audioEnc.SyncStateWithParent();
                  var audioSinkPad = muxer.GetRequestPad("audio_%u");
                  if (audioSinkPad != null)
                  {
                      if (audioQueue.Link(audioConvert) == true &&
                          audioConvert.Link(audioEnc) == true &&
                          audioEnc.GetStaticPad("src").Link(audioSinkPad) == PadLinkReturn.Ok)
                      {
                          Console.WriteLine("Audio pad linked successfully.");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Console.WriteLine("Failed to link audio elements to muxer.");
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Failed to get audio sink pad from muxer.");
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine($"Failed to link audio pad to audio queue sink pad.");
              }
          }
      };

      var bus = pipeline.Bus;
      bus.AddSignalWatch();
      bus.Message += (o, args) => OnMessage(o, args, pipelineName, cameraId, cameraName);

      var stateChangeReturn = pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);
      if (stateChangeReturn == StateChangeReturn.Failure)
      {
          pipeline.Dispose();
          Console.WriteLine($"Failed to start recording of {cameraName}");
          return null;
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"Recording begin of {cameraName}");
          return pipeline;
      }
  }

I have tried setting up a GStreamer pipeline in C# to record both video and audio from an RTSP stream and mux them into a single MP4 file. Here is the approach I followed:
Created and initialized necessary GStreamer elements such as rtspsrc, videodepay, audiodepay, audioenc, muxer, and various queue and conversion elements.
Set properties on the elements and linked them appropriately.
Listened for the PadAdded signal on the rtspsrc element to dynamically link the incoming audio and video streams.
Added the elements to the pipeline and set the pipeline to the Playing state.
